# Question about Timer Control in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have some query about my code, I am using **VB6.0** and I have a question using TimerControl... The user will first Login[***frmLogin***] and then the **UserID** and **Password** must recognize whether it is **Admin** or **Guest**. Once it was recognized as **Admin**, the user will be redirected to the **frmAdmin** and if not, he will be redirected to **frmEmployee** after the Timer[**tmLogin**]/Progressbar[**pgLogin**] **reaches 100%**. I'm just perplexed because I am using database with two tables[**tblEmployee** & **tblPosition**]. Each Table has an index: **idxid** for **tblEmployee** and **idxpost** for **tblPosition**... I don't know where to insert the conditional statement... Please help me out, once it was resolved, it will be my rule for the further problem that I might encounter... Thanks in advance. Here is my code

```
Private Sub cmdContinue_Click()
Dim boolLogedIn As Boolean
    If Me.txtUserID.Text = "" And Me.txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        Me.lblWarning.Caption = "*User ID and Password must not be a null."
        Me.tmLoginformSize.Enabled = True
        Me.txtUserID.SetFocus
        Beep
    ElseIf Me.txtUserID.Text = "" Then
        Me.lblWarning.Caption = "*User ID must not be a null."
        Me.tmLoginformSize.Enabled = True
        Me.txtUserID.SetFocus
        Beep
    ElseIf Me.txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        Me.lblWarning.Caption = "*Password must not be a null."
        Me.tmLoginformSize.Enabled = True
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
        Beep
    Else
        Do Until datLogin.Recordset.EOF
            With datLogin.Recordset
                If Me.txtUserID.Text = !empid And Me.txtPassword.Text = !Password Then
                    boolLogedIn = True
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    datLogin.Recordset.MoveNext
                End If
            End With
        Loop
        If boolLogedIn = True Then
            Me.tmLogin.Enabled = True
            Me.lblConnecting.Visible = True
            Me.lblLoginPercent.Visible = True
            Me.pbLogin.Visible = True
        Else
            Me.lblWarning.Caption = "*User ID and Password did not match."
            Me.datLogin.Recordset.MoveFirst
            Me.tmLoginformSize.Enabled = True
            Beep
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub tmLogin_Timer()
    With Me.pbLogin
        Me.pbLogin.Value = Me.pbLogin.Value + 1
        Me.lblLoginPercent.Caption = Str(Me.pbLogin.Value) + "%"
        If Me.pbLogin.Value >= 1 And Me.pbLogin.Value < 50 Then
            Me.lblConnecting.Caption = "Connecting..."
        ElseIf Me.pbLogin.Value >= 50 And Me.pbLogin.Value < 100 Then
            Me.lblConnecting.Caption = "Logging in..."
        Else
            Me.lblConnecting.Caption = "Done..."
            frmLogin.Hide
            frmEmployee.Show
            Me.tmLogin.Enabled = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

...Here is my screenshots
[image: my tables]

[image: my frmLogin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would accomplish what you are looking for with minimal changes to 
your code :

```
'Add this declaration 
Dim m_intLoggedInUserType As Integer

Private Sub cmdContinue_Click()
    'Unchanged code

        Do Until datLogin.Recordset.EOF
            With datLogin.Recordset
                If Me.txtUserID.Text = !empid And Me.txtPassword.Text = !Password Then
                    boolLogedIn = True
                    m_intLoggedInUserType = !postId
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    datLogin.Recordset.MoveNext
                End If
            End With
        Loop

        'More unchanged code
End Sub

Private Sub tmLogin_Timer()
    With Me.pbLogin
        'Unchanged code

            Me.lblConnecting.Caption = "Done..."
            frmLogin.Hide

            if m_intLoggendInUserType = 1 Then 
               frmAdmin.Show
            Else
               frmEmployee.Show
            End If

            Me.tmLogin.Enabled = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

You should take note of Rasel's answer as well, since working directly with the connection and the recordset objects are preferable to the datacontrol.

Comment: Thaks... I got it with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough. If you want to load a form according to Administrator or other you can use like this

```
dim r as new adodb.recordset
r.open "select postid from tblemployee",db,adopendynamic,adlockoptimistic,adcmdtext

'db is your adodb.connection

if r.eof then
    msgbox "name/pass not matched"
    exit sub
else
    'do whatever you like with your postid in r.fields(0)
end if
```

Comment: ...Would you mind asking you what is the purpose of these `,db,adopendynamic,adlockoptimistic,adcmdtext`... Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should take a look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544(v=VS.85).aspx). It gives a brief description of each parameter.